# Gmail API - Wrong exception fired when user's Gmail account is disabled

Tags: gmail-api

I'm working on a C# project that use Gmail API in single-user mode to retrieve user's mail. The application is working nicely.

Recently, we got a strange behavior from this API. When the user hasn't a @gmail account with Gmail disabled and try to use our product, for some we got a "Bad Request 400" with "Mail service not enabled" exception and for other users, we got "Bad Request 400" with "failedPrecondition" exception.

The users are on the same domain name. I searched through Gmail API documentation and I found nothing that can explain this.

Our thoughts are that maybe some users have different settings in their Google account that can cause the "general" "failedPrecondition".

Any advice?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean to say this happens when user's email is not of Gmail - like yahoo,etc?

Comment: @noogui Yes, like someone@domainname.com